# Variable refactoring and multi-selection

Tags: syntax-highlighting, editing, refactoring

In IDEs like PyCharm for Python, I can select a variable name or method name and it will highlight to show where all I have used it. Also its easy to refactor the names under a given text selection.

Is it possible to *do* this in MMA?

Below is a Python example in PyCharm IDE where "*key*" is a variable I would like to refactor and also see where all it is used.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

There is a Wolfram Language plugin for the IDEs you mention: https://wlplugin.halirutan.de

It supports refactoring in this way.

Notice below how `values` is highlighted only within the first `Module` but not elsewhere.

[image]